# JavaScript: function in variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

At the moment I do a course about JavaScript on codecademy.

Now I got to a task where i need to create a function in a variable.
Can anyone explain to me why i can do functions in a variable?

I don't know why I should be able to do this.
After all I can call the function with it's own name.

Big thanks for every helpful answer!

Comment: That is beauty of JavaScript ! Many other languages has this feature. What is the problem with that?

Comment: There's no difference between a string, a number, *a function* or other types in Javascript. They're all simple values and can be assigned to variables. That's all.

Comment: There's nothing special, a function declared as statement (that requires identifier) is declared as first variable of its scope, FYI

Comment: Well, by the same logic you could ask "why a number in a variable" or "why a string in a variable". After all you can use the number/string directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn

Answer (score 2):

This is because javascript supports first class functions, or in other words, functions in javacsript are objects.
So you can pass them to a variable, pass them as argument to a function, return them in a function, etc.

I hope this will be helpful. If not, tell me.